# ido-find-file: lists of results in wrong order

Tags: ido

When using `C-x C-f` (ido-find-file) to open files use I can use `M-s` to enable fuzzy matching.

If I type `C-x C-f` then `M-s` and then enter the the fuzzy search string, things work as they should.

However if I type `C-x C-f` then enter the fuzzy string and then type `M-s` I get something like this in the minibuffer:

> my-fuzzy-search[correct-completion]{some-totally-unrelated-file |
>   correct-completion | ... }

Some unrelated file is always first in the list of results, and if I press enter here ido will open it. Is there a way to configure ido so that the correct match will be first in the list in this case?

Comment: FWIW, Ido does not really use what is usually called *fuzzy matching*. It uses what it calls *flex* matching (which is what Icicles calls [*scatter* matching](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion#ScatterMatchCompletion)), which is kind of a poor man's fuzzy matching. (Nothing wrong with it - just saying...)

Answer (score 4):

Ido doesn't have very smart fuzzy matching by default.  Essentially, if you put in

```
horse
```

Ido will try to match

```
.*h.*o.*r.*s.*e.*
```

against its candidates.  This isn't really how we think about matching, since we would expect a file literally called `horse-feathers.txt` to score higher than `hogs-raging-senial.png`.

Check out the [`flx-ido`](https://github.com/lewang/flx) package.  From the [readme](https://github.com/lewang/flx#usage):

> The sorting algorithm is a balance between word beginnings
>   (abbreviation) and contiguous matches (substring).
>
> The longer the substring match, the higher it scores.  This maps well
>   to how we think about matching.
>
> In general, it's better form queries with only lowercase characters so
>   the sorting algorithm can do something smart.
>
> For example, if you have these files:
>
> ```
>     projects/clojure-mode/clojure-mode.el
>     projects/prelude/core/prelude-mode.el
> ```
>
> If the search term was *pre-mode*, you might expect "prelude-mode.el"
>   to rank higher.  However because the substring match "re-mode" is so
>   long, "clojure-mode.el" actually scores higher.
>
> **Here, using *premode* would give the expected order.** Notice that the "-" actually prevents the algorithm from helping you.
>
> #### uppercase letters
>
> Flx always folds lowercase letters to match uppercase.  However, you
>   can use uppercase letters for force flx to only match uppercase.
>
> This is similar to Emacs' case-folding.  The difference is mixing in
>   uppercase letters **does not disable** folding.
>
> #### completing file names
>
> Matches within the basepath score higher.

Comment: This works better, but I can still get situations where the completion I want is in [] brackets in the beginning, but further down in the {} list. If I write the beginning of a filename with wrong case, this file will end up further down the list, compared to a file with the same letters further apart but with the right case. However the first file will be shown within the square brackets.

Comment: Again, `In general, it's better form queries with only lowercase characters so the sorting algorithm can do something smart.`  Why use `Shift` when you don't have to?

Comment: When I write with all lowercase, and the match I want has some uppercase characters, then the situation in my first comment happens.